# Calculate the number of regular users in mysql

Tags: mysql

Given the table showed in the picture, I want to calculate the number of users who have dates far in more than one day. Basically the problem is to calculate the number of regular visitors.

[image: table]

For example: The user `adrian@` have 3 timestamps, 2 of them in the same day and the other one 2 days after, so this user came back. Instead, the user `david@` only have 2 timestamps (in the same day), that means this user didn't come back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT usuario_email
FROM users
GROUP BY usuario_email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(fecha)) > 1
```

The above will select users having visited your site in 2 or more different dates, hence it will select only `adrian@` based on your sample data.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f7b9/1)